# Break program flow with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wonder what would be the proper way of breaking the flow of the program and redirect to some route.

Something like the equivalent of a header redirection but using route names instead of the complete URL.

This is quite [common to be found in PHP frameworks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control) and quite powerful, and I haven't found yet the way of doing it with express.js.

Imagine this scenario:

```
function getUser() {
    //...
    //getting user..

    //Here I would like to break the flow of the program
    if (error) {
        res.redirect('add');
    }

    //If there was no error we keep the normal flow
    //...
}


router.get('/add', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = getUser();
    var date = //whatever
    var type = //whatever

    var event = createEvent(user, date, type);

    res.render('add', {
        date: date,
        type: type,
        whatever: whatever,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        message: req.flash('error')
    });
});
```

A normal `render` wouldn't be what I want, because I don't want having to get again all the variables needed to render the view, I would like the route I want to redirect to deal with it.

I was thinking about using `writeHead`, but that would require the whole URL, not just the route URL.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `false` or `null` or some other value from `getUser()` to indicate a break. Or check the state of the response (e.g. check `res._headerSent === true` or `res.finished === true`).

Another possibility might be to look into making `getUser()` a middleware function. Example:

```
function getUser(req, res, next) {
  // ...

  if (error)
    return res.redirect('add');

  // If there was no error we keep the normal flow
  // ...

  // you would add user data to `req` here instead of returning it
  req.user = ...

  next();
}

router.get('/add', getUser, function(req, res, next) {
    var user = req.user;
    var date = //whatever
    var type = //whatever

    var event = createEvent(user, date, type);

    res.render('add', {
      date: date,
      type: type,
      whatever: whatever,
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
      message: req.flash('error')
    });
});
```